# Moving the blog page

Tags: posts

I have done the typical procedure to change the home page to a static page, and move the posts page to a /blog page.

Home page is fine, but the 'blog' page  shows the same as the home page, even when I select a custom template which has the loop in, it just ignores that and displays the home page template, any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2):

When you are selecting a static page as homepage, you can use an existing page(or a new page) to select as blog page.
It won't need any custom code to display anything.

If you want to display a blog on a page which as a slug `/blog/` to display the blog layout with your own code, then don't select anything for the blog page at the settings page where you have selected the static page.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply!

I have tried using 'Default template' which shows the same thing as when I selected a custom template 'blog' no matter what I select it shows no blog layout on /blog

Comment: you don't need to select any custom template or page template. Try creating a new page and select that as a blog page in settings. Don't use any code or anything else.